# Invalid character in the given encoding in "npm install" nodemailer

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I tried

```
npm install -g mongodb formidable nodemailer simplesmtp imap
```

After I got an error in red line:

```
.....AppData.....node_modules\iconv\build\icovcxproj(40,47)> error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 40, position 47. ... 

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing iconv@1.2.3 ...
```

and after some ERR! rows.

What can I do?

*(Op: Windows 8 )*

Comment: this could help https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/20

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is with installing one of the dependencies, [`iconv`](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv).

You should show us the output of `npm install -g iconv`. And if you can, [post it to the project's issue list](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv/issues/new).

I'm not sure which of the projects (mongodb formidable nodemailer simplesmtp imap) has iconv as a dependency, but installing them separately should let you know.

```
npm install -g mongodb
npm install -g formidable
npm install -g nodemailer
...
```